# DEX died after Android Debug Bridge (ADB) Bloatware Removal

Tags: applications, adb, hardware, samsung-dex

I decided to debloat my Samsung Note 20 Ultra phone of all the garbage apps Samsung installs. I used ADB shell to perform this bloatware removal and the list shown below identifies all the Samsung bloatware app names which I used as a guide in my removal process.

Everything went perfectly except for the fact I mistakenly uninstalled DEX which is an app that allows me to connect my Note 20 Ultra to a monitor via an HDMI connection. Once the connection is established DEX would automatically start and magically generate a "Windows Like" desktop GUI on the monitor. In short, my DEX is no longer working in the same way it was working before I performed the debloat process.

I hope somebody in this community can identify to me which Samsung parent app from the list shown below is the DEX app subordinate to? Because my theory is the DEX app is hiding inside one of the parent apps shown below and what is not making it easy is how the word "DEX" is nowhere to be seen. Therefore, I hope somebody can tell me which of the Samsung apps shown below I should leave untouched so my DEX app remains operational.

Any tips welcome.

```
:Samsung Bloatware App Removal List
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.service.livedrawing           ::Penup app
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.kidsinstaller             ::Kids Mode
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.storyservice                  ::Samsung Story video collage app, now defunct.
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.service.peoplestripe          ::Access contacts etc from Edge Screen
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.app.galaxyfinder          ::Phone Search App
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.service.airviewdictionary     ::Samsung Translate
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.easysetup             ::Smart Things setup
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.beaconmanager             ::Bluetooth beacon service, location tracking and smart things
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.scloud                ::Samsung Cloud Service
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.spayfw                ::Framework for Samsung Pay
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.samsungpass               ::Biometric replacement for web logins etc
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.authfw                ::Samsung Authentication Framework for Samsung Pass
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.samsungpassautofill           ::Samsung Pass autofill
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.app.watchmanagerstub          ::Galaxy Gear Watch App
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.svoiceime             ::Samsung Voice Input
pm uninstall --user 0 com.sec.android.app.billing               ::Samsung Billing
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.app.simplesharing         ::Samsung Link Sharing (Using Samsung Cloud)
pm uninstall --user 0 com.sec.android.cover.ledcover                ::LED Phone Cover Service
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.rubin.app             ::Customisation Service
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.stickercenter             ::Call Stikers, discontinued by Samsung
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.aremoji               ::AR Emoji
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.livestickers              ::Deco Pic, Photo decoration app
pm uninstall --user 0 com.diotek.sec.lookup.dictionary              ::Samsung Dictionary
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.app.social                ::What's New, Samsung Social. Samsung Social Network with Contacts
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.forest                ::Digital Wellbeing and parental controls
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.ardrawing             ::AR Doodle, drawing on photos and video in 3D
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.arzone                ::AR Zone, Provides AR features.
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.app.tips              ::Tips, User manual and usage tips.
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.aremojieditor
pm uninstall --user 0 com.sec.android.mimage.avatarstickers
pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.kgclient              ::Payment Services
```

Comment: Do factory reset and disable one by one until you figured out

Comment: I had the same idea to isolate the DEX app by doing an uninstall one by one. However, I was hoping somebody in this community would read this post and tell me what specific Samsung app I need to leave alone so my DEX app remains operational.

Answer (score 0):

Others I don't know but you'd need to keep finder as finder is a search framework that is also used in dex.
There may be more apps you need to leave alone